# searching for parentheses in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Writing a program where I read in a list of words/symbols from one file and search for each one in another body of text.

So it's something like:

```
while(<FILE>){
    $findword = $_;

    for (@text){
        if ($_=~ /$find/){
            push(@found, $_);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I run into trouble once parentheses show up. It gives me this error:

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE
```

I realize it's because Perl thinks the `(` is part of the regex, but how do I deal with this and make the `(` searchable?

Comment: If you don't want regex metacharacters to be meta, then do not use a regular expression at all. The 2nd part of @mu is too short's answer is the Right Thing for what you are trying to do (it will be much much faster too)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`\Q` and `\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters):

```
if ($_ =~ /\Q$find\E/){
```

Or just use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) if you're just looking for a literal match:

```
if(index($_, $find) >= 0) {
```

Comment: Yes, index is the way if you're just looking for a constant string.

Answer (score 3):

In general backslash escapes characters inside regexes - i.e. `/\(/` will match a literal `(`

in situations like this it's better to use the quote operator

```
if ( $_ =~ /\Q$find\E/ ) {
    ...
}
```

alternatively use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do `/\Q$find\E/` instead of just `/$find/` - the `\Q` tells the parser to stop considering metacharacters as part of the regex until it finds the `\E`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will find `m/\Q$find\E/` useful - unless you want other Perl regex metacharacters to be interpreted as metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

`\Q` with `\e` will escape your special chars in the `$find` variable like:

```
while(<FILE>){
    $findword = $_;

    for (@text){
        if ($_=~ /\Q$find\e/){
            push(@found, $_);
        }
    }
}
```